Cauchy but not convergent sequence on $C[-1,1]$

Consider $C[-1,1] = \{ f: [-1,1] \rightarrow \Bbb{R}: f$ is continuous $\}$, the inner product $\langle f,g \rangle = \int_{-1}^1 f(x)g(x) \, dx$ and $\lVert \cdot \rVert$ the induced norm. Then, the sequence defined as 
$$f_n(x)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc} 0 & \text{if} & -1 \leq x \leq 0 \\ nx & \text{if} & 0 \leq x \leq 1/n \\ 1 & \text{if} & 1/n < x \leq 1\end{array} \right.$$
is a Cauchy but not convergent sequence of $(C[-1,1], \lVert \cdot \rVert)$

I am trying to prove this in order to show that $(C[-1,1], \lVert \cdot \rVert)$ is not complete. If we denote
$$f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc} 0 & \text{if} & -1 \leq x \leq 0 \\ 1 & \text{if} & 0 < x \leq 1 \end{array} \right.$$
it is clear that $f \in L_2[-1,1] \setminus C[-1,1]$ and that $f_n \rightarrow_{n \rightarrow \infty} f$ on $L_2 [-1,1]$, which I think it is fine to prove that it does not converges.
Despite, I am having difficulties when proving that $\{f_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence. I have tried to take $n, m \in \Bbb{N}: 0 \leq m, 1 \leq n$ and search for a relation between $n$ and $\varepsilon >0$ so use the definition and that: $$\lVert f_n - f_{n+m} \rVert ^2  = \int_{-1}^1 (f_n(x) - f_{n+m}(x))^2 dx = \int_0^{\frac{1}{n+m}} x^2 dx + \int_{\frac{1}{n+m}}^{\frac{1}{n}} (n-1)^2 x^2 dx = \frac{1}{3(n+m)^3} + \frac{(n-1)^2}{3} \cdot \left[ \frac{1}{n^3} - \frac{1}{(n+m)^3} \right]$$
but I am not reaching anything, so any possible help would be very appreciated.
EDIT
We can observe that $f\in L_2[-1,1] \setminus C[-1,1]$ and :
$$\lVert f - f_n \rVert ^2 = \int_0^{\frac{1}{n}}(nx-1)^2dx=\frac{1}{3n} \cdot (nx-1)^3 |_{x=0}^{x=1/n} =\frac{1}{3n} \implies \\ \implies\lVert f - f_n \rVert = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3n}} \rightarrow_{n \rightarrow \infty} 0$$
Therefore $f = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n$ on $L_2[-1,1]$ . Now, convergent implies Cauchy on every metric space, so $\{f_n\}$ is Cauchy on $L_2[-1,1]$ and then it is on $C[-1,1]$ . Finally, if $\{f_n\}$ would be convergent on $C[-1,1]$, by limit uniqueness $f \in C[-1,1]$, which is absurd, so $\{f_n\}$ is not convergent on $C[-1,1]$ .

Hint: $n + m \geq n - 1$.

@mihaild I have tried to use it, but I do not see on which part of the last equation should help, can you tell me?

$\left |\frac{1}{n^3} - \frac{1}{(n + m)^2}\right| \leq \frac{2}{(n - 1)^3}$ (actually it can be made stronger, but this is already enough)

Can you say a bit more about why it's clear that $f_n \to f$ in $L^1$, and why it's clear that implies $f_n$ does not converge in $C[-1, 1]$? For the former - I agree it's true, but I don't see why this is so much "more clear" than $f_n$ being Cauchy. For the latter - bear in mind that these two spaces are equipped with different norms! Anyway, I think you're doing too much work. You can use a bound like $\int_a^b |g(x)|^2,\mathrm dx \le (b - a) \lVert g \rVert_\infty^2$ here, avoiding any calculation.

@IzaakvanDongen My mistake, I mean $L_2$, not $L_1$, I have updated, thanks for noticing! For the last equation, in this case that would imply that $\lVert f_{n+m} - f_n \rVert^2 \leq 2 \cdot (\frac{m}{n+m})^2 $ , the problem is, how to find the relation between $n$ and $\varepsilon$ here? I mean how to prove that this implies Cauchy

No worries! If it really is clear to you $f_n \to f$ in $L^2$, then this instantly shows that $f_n$ is Cauchy (it converges in $L^2$, hence it must be Cauchy in $L^2$, hence it's Cauchy in $C[-1, 1]$). This argument works for any sequence $x_n$ in a metric space $X$ that converges when $X$ is isometrically embedded in a larger metric space $Y$. But I suspect that $f_n \to f$ is not as clear as you think if $f_n$ being Cauchy isn't clear.

@IzaakvanDongen This is perfect, thank you so much!

You're welcome! To show that $f_n$ is Cauchy directly, what I meant was that $|f_n - f_{n + m}|$ is at most $2$, and it's zero outside of $[0, \frac 1n]$, so $\lVert f_n - f_{n + m} \rVert^2$ is at most $\frac 1n \cdot 2^2$.
